# Generating .PDFs from a Drupal View

Tags: views

I'm working on a Drupal 7 Commerce site for a nonprofit and they are interested in generating year-end financial statements for their donors. With https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator, I've been able to create a View which renders the desired output calculating the total donations for the year.

The user profile contains a field which allows donors to request a paper receipt to be mailed at year's end. Using https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf I can generate a .pdf.

What I'm lacking is a way to generate all of the needed paper files without visiting and printing pages one at a time. https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf/issues/1415380#comment-5701968 seems to address this (almost) but I'm yet to get this approach to function properly.

I'm surprised there is not a Commerce-centric module for this. If I've missed it, please let me know. Or, is there a tutorial explaining to save a file to the server based on a View's output? And what is the best way to trigger this? Seemingly Rules could be used to update a receipt every time a Commerce order is completed, but I'd prefer that the accounting department is able to hit a "Generate receipts" button to trigger this which would result in either files being saved to the server or a print job being created.

Thank you

Comment: You could probably solve this by using [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) + [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

Comment: No Sssweat, you rock! Using https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations/issues/834448#comment-3144750 as a starting point  (Note: in my case advanced actions were not needed), I created a "Destination" View which returns the entities as I want them to be printed. I then created a "Source" VBO View where "Pass ids as arguments to a page" is selected and the Operation settings URL is that of the destination view. It works perfectly. Thank you!